# How can I read from this file and turn it to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've tried several methods to read from this file and turn it to a dictionary but I'm having a lot of errors

I've tried the following method but it did not work I got **not enough values unpack**.

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[int(key)] = val
```

I want to read and convert it to this:

`{123: ['Ahmed Rashed', 'a', '1000.0'], 456: ['Noof Khaled', 'c', '0.0'], 777: ['Ali Mahmood', 'a', '4500.0']}`

[image: File]

Comment: Can you please just include the text file as text instead of linking to a blurry image?

Comment: `split()` with no arguments splits on whitespace. It seems you want to split at commas instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on commas instead.

```py
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         parts = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
         d[int(parts[0])] = parts[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csv.reader` to read the file and split it into its fields:

```
import csv
with open("file.txt") as f:
    d = {
        int(num): data
        for num, *data in csv.reader(f)
    }
```